# swap .has_khey by something else in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I know that in python3 ".has_khey" is replace by "in"

But in my exemple , i didn't manage for make it working .

the whole quote for execution

```
from sklearn import model_selection
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import neighbors, metrics
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('your_path/winequality-red.csv', sep=";")
X = data.as_matrix([data.columns[:-1]])

y = data.as_matrix([data.columns[-1]])
y.flatten()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = \
model_selection.train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3)
knn= neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = 12)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
```

the part which return me error :

```
sizes = {} 
for (yt, yp) in zip(list(y_test), list(y_pred)):
   if sizes.has_key((yt, yp)):
      sizes[(yt, yp)] += 1
   else:
      sizes[(yt, yp)] = 1

keys = sizes.keys()
plt.scatter([k[0] for k in keys], [k[1] for k in keys], s=[sizes[k] for k in keys], color='coral')
```

when i try  to swap `if sizes.has_key((yt, yp)):`  in  `if (yt, yp) in sizes:`

I got the error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

[download the wine database](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv)

thanks in advance for any help

the result i'm looking for :
[plot scatter size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5J8k.png)

[here the .ipynb or .py file](https://github.com/lelchim/OpenClassroom/tree/master)

Comment: See [mcve] and make your example runnable.

Comment: okey i just edited it , you can execute it now, i didn't though to give the whole code because i'm using jupyter note book

Comment: Not really, what is `y_pred`? After pasting the code in the question, you may just try to run it yourself to check if you have created a  [mcve] or not.

Comment: Ok, but independent of that, one can already say that you cannot use numpy arrays as keys.

Comment: My bad i forget to copy past the prediction, it's update.
For your answer,  i don't think it's a np arraway i made a matrix  with the csv file .
I didn't use np.array anywhere, the code shouldn't work because it's a teacher who did it.
My only problem is about the fact  that has_khey is not include  in Py3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the code you show can actually produce the error you report. Possibly you have redefined some variable in the notebook outside of that code?

In any case, concerning the question, you would want to replace `if sizes.has_key((yt, yp)):`  by

```
if (yt, yp) in sizes.keys():
```

This should give you the desired plot

[image]

Comment: I just  upload a github like with .ipynb and .py   .
U can   check it. it's exactly what I wrote in my post and it return  the same error with ur solution `if (yt, yp) in sizes.keys():`

Comment: I can run your example just fine when accounting for the fact that `data.as_matrix` returns all nans in the newest pandas version and hence replacing it with `data.values`. Maybe you want to tell which exact versions of python and all libraries your are using? Also mind that comments like `# In[50]:` indicate that there is some code being run before the shown code which could be responsible for any failures. A [mcve] should of course make sure such things to be reproducible.

Comment: don't take attention of the `#In[50]` it's just when I run a cell with **ctrl+entry** on **jupyter notebook**, it's increase the `#In[i]`.
Otherwise, I'm using  **anaconda navigator** and the version of python in the navigator is `python 3.6.1`, futhermore, it mean "i'm using" all lib included in **anaconda navigator**.

Comment: I mean what should I say to that... If one cell is executed after another, it needs to be `#In[i+1]`, else just anything can happen. So if you haven't restarted the kernel and run everything top to bottom, it may not result in anything useful. Apart, if you don't tell the versions in use, I cannot recheck, but I can of course tell you the versions I am using: pandas 0.23.1, numpy 1.14.2, sklearn 0.19.1, on python 3.6.4 from anaconda. With this and the above mentionned change of `X = data[data.columns[:-1]].values` and `y = data[data.columns[-1]].values` I get the correct output.

Comment: okay i replaced X and y with your line , it work for me too !
thank you very much !!

Comment: one last question : what do you means by "nans" in "returns all nans in the newest pandas version and hence replacing it with"

Comment: "nan" means "not a number". In case numpy cannot compute something numerically the result may be a `numpy.nan`. In the above case, the resulting arrays are filled with `numpy.nan`s, which I called nans. Sorry for the impressision.